# Bayesian Priors Update: Difference in Mean detection

Tags: time-series, bayesian, change-point

Suppose I have measures of the life span of mice. I know the true expectancy in the beginning of the experiment - 1000 of days and true variance.

At some (unknown) point mice begun to be fed by a new drug. New drug increase or decrease the life expectancy. I would say small effects are more probable than large effects, but mice on drugs can live, for example, 5 times longer, with extremely small prior probability, and it is impossible to live 10 times longer.

So I have three models: $M_{increase}, M_{same}, M_{decrease}$. But I am not interested in small changes of life expectancy, so $M_{same}$ means "life expectancy is something within 990-1010".

So, I have all the data and need to find a change in life expectancy (it happened once and after this point all mice were under drugs). I can simply check all data points in time series and find the maximum likelihood solution (with a t-test), but I would like to do it in a Bayesian way using, for example, Bayes factors.

Which priors should I choose? How to update priors for these models? I could not find conjugate prior with this decreasing trend in the beginning of analysis and with growing "pike" around true value in the end.

UPD: I want to fill 2 matrices (dynamic programming) with the Bayes factors between alternative/neutral models. Lets say "model changes at moment $t$". That means that corresponding Bayes factor will be the biggest one (± several points). Here is the example for 5 time points, maximum BF at the coordinate (2,5) means "model changed at moment 2 and till point 5 alternative model was preferable". (Actually, that's how I can detect the switch off to neutral model). The problem here is that I do not know the distribution of alternative model, but I know that it has constant mean and variance.

`time-points     1   2   3   4   5
              1 0.5 0.7 0.8 1.1 1.4
              2     1.5 1.8 3.6 4.9
              3         2.0 3.2 3.9
              4             1.8 2.5
              5                 0.9`

Comment: Do you know the distribution of treatment onset times, at least?

Comment: No, it is the goal - to find a moment of a treatment's start (it will be seen as a changepoint). It can be easily solved by hypothesis testing (using t-test at all possible treatment's starts), but it is somehow extremely difficult for me from Bayesian point of view.

Comment: Aha, right. Change point analysis is actually pretty natural from the Bayesian perspective, e.g. Barry and Hartigan 1993 (implemented in the `bcp` R package: https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v007i02). This may be an easier framework to work with than distinct models and their Bayes Factors.

Comment: Thank you. The problem is that signal/noise in data is actually really big...and bcp and alternatives shows really bad performance. They can detect any change in regression, but here just the regressions $y = 0 * x + a$ should be considered. In contrast method with matrices of BFs worked extremely well for known effect changes, now I am trying to generalise it for unknown intercept...Also, it is offline analysis, so weak prior on possible effects can be created...but I do not know how to move next =(

Comment: @conjugateprior this is actually non-Bayesian version of what I am talking about: http://biostatistics.oxfordjournals.org/content/5/4/557.full.pdf . It does not require alternative hypothesis. What I want to do is to make it Bayesian (the accuracy will benefit a lot from this and it was shown for known effect sizes)...